# How to disable Smart Reply in the new Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I like the new Gmail, and I like Inbox form Gmail, but I really cannot stand the "Smart Replies" feature, those poor already-made replies at the bottom of messages.
In the mobile app it is possible to disable the feature, but I cannot understand why this is not possible in the web version!

How can I disable Smart Reply?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**UPDATE 10/1/18**: You can now disable Smart Reply from Gmail's [General Settings](https://mail.google.com/mail/#settings/general) page. Scroll down to the Smart Reply section.

[image]

(**PRIOR HACK FOR DISABLING**: Use adblock. You can use Adblock for Chrome or any other adblock browser extension. It is just a `div` element with `class="brb"`. If you want to add it manually the custom filter is `mail.google.com##DIV[class="brb"]`, but depending on which extension you use you can usually right click the smart reply element and select "block".)

Comment: i am using Adblock too... 
Saadly it looks like they do not care about all the people that are asking for a simple toggle to switch it off...

Comment: they're probably trying to get enough data in order to improve their smart reply algorithms before they allow users to turn it off

Comment: I just Adblocked it myself, it feels strange using it for Gmail of all things. I also wish I could turn it off. Adblock worked.

Comment: `mail.google.com##DIV[class="brb"]` works for UblockOrigin as well. Go to the "dashboard" and then the "My Filters" tab.